# Working in MySQL, missing right parenthesis in Oracle

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

For a class project we are using MySQL and Oracle to create a database and write queries to select data.

This query:

```
 SELECT     E1.EmployeeID, E1.FirstName, E1.LastName 
 FROM   EMPLOYEE AS E1 
 WHERE  EXISTS         
 (SELECT E2.LastName         
 FROM EMPLOYEE AS E2         
 WHERE E1.LastName = E2.LastName 
 AND E1.EmployeeID <> E2.EmployeeID);
```

works fine on MySQL and returns two results, but on Oracle I get an error message after E1 saying that I am missing a right parenthesis. Is there actually somewhere i need to add parentheses or is there another issue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `AS` to make it work on Oracle:

```
SELECT     E1.EmployeeID, E1.FirstName, E1.LastName 
FROM   EMPLOYEE E1 -- here
WHERE  EXISTS         
     (SELECT E2.LastName         
      FROM EMPLOYEE E2  -- here   
      WHERE E1.LastName = E2.LastName 
        AND E1.EmployeeID <> E2.EmployeeID);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b6f54898acb8fd7531323569f503cd5a)**

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly. I am having another problem between Oracle and MySQL with another version of this query.

Comment: @karlb22 - so you understand the answer: In Oracle, you can give aliases to columns, and also to tables and subqueries. When you give an alias to a column, you **may** use the keyword `AS` (it's optional, but it may be good for clarity). For tables and subqueries, though, you **may not** use the keyword `AS`. As you found out, MySQL has different rules. This is a typical experience when you work with competing products supposed to do essentially the same job.

Comment: @mathguy thank you! I have another question but it might be better formatted as a separate post on here so once my 90 minute limit is up i will post it. It is similar to this query but pulls duplicate names from two different tables (SELECT C1.LastName         
      FROM CUSTOMER C1    
      WHERE E1.LastName = C1.LastName 
        AND E1.FirstName = C1.FirstName) . It returns 4 results in MySQL but no results in Oracle despite them having the same data

Comment: @karlb22: this is likely to come from your data, not from you using a different SQL dialect. Make sure to provide proper sample data, current and desired results if you ask a question for that.

Comment: @GMB Will make sure to do that. Thanks